# Subdomain-based URL configuration in Django app

Tags: python, django

**General idea:**
For example, user John have created two pages with urls /about/ and /about/contacts/ and his domain is john.app.com. 
User Bob have created three pages with urls /company/, /news/, /store/ and his domain is bob.app.com. So, if user goes to site john.app.com, I want to load url scheme with 2 urls, and if user goes to bob.app.com, I want to use scheme with 3 url patterns...

I'm using the django-subdomains package to use different url schemes for different subdomains. Basically to realize my idea, I need to get the current subdomain and fetch from DB available pages urls for that subdomain BEFORE Django starts serving url patterns. Does anyone have an idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution... It's not very clever, but it works:

In my urls.py, I wrote the rule, that accepts all requests and points them to page_dispatcher view:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', 'app.account.site.views.page_dispatcher'),
   url(r'^(?P<path>.+)$', 'app.account.site.views.page_dispatcher'),
)
```

After that, in my views.py I've created the dynamic url configuration and use the resolve() function to resolve view that corresponds to requested path:

```
class DynamicURLConf(object):
    urlpatterns = None

    def __init__(self, pages):
        self.urlpatterns = patterns('',
                                    url(r'^$', 'app.account.site.views.test'),
                                    url(r'^test/$', 'app.account.site.views.test'),
        )


def page_dispatcher(request, path=None):
    if path is None:
        # Here will be a return a homepage view
        return
    func, args, kwargs = resolve(urlparse("/" + path.strip("/") + "/")[2], DynamicURLConf(pages=None))
    kwargs['request'] = request
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("I am test")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do so!
you should konw that when deploy a website with appache2 + mod_wsgi

`wsgi.py` you will find `settings.py`
and in `settings.py` you find corresponding `urls.py`

so just use two or more `settings.py` and `urls.py` in project

and change your apache configration file

john.app.com -> john.conf -> john.wsgi.py -> john.settings.py -> john.urls.py

see here:http://www.besttome.com/html/run_multiple_websites_one_django_project.html

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I need. I don't know how many users will be registered on my service, so I can't create urls.py for them.

Comment: @astrikovd just write a dynamic urls.py,use request.user to judge who is,and fetch from DB related pages, and put them into urlpatterns

Comment: request object is not accessible from urls.py.

Comment: ok,you can render urls of some user to template, but urls.py include urls of all users. You can also do it with a prefix,https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters

Comment: @astrikovd maybe useful to you:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls

Comment: Thank you for help, but i found another solution - create generic URL conf and use resolve() function to resolve corresponding view.

Comment: OK,if you have a better solution,you could share with others and accept the answer yourself!

Comment: Ok, I've posted the solution, hope it will be useful for someone.